# How do I get a node by its ID?

Tags: 8, nodes

Using `{{ drupal_entity('node', '123', 'body') }}` in a template file, I can get the node body and title.

Is there a way to get all the available node properties?

Comment: The last parameter is a view mode, not a field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution is to [preprocess the node](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/modifying-attributes-in-a-theme-file).

If you want to avoid coding PHP, you can use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak), which has a handy [list of twig commands it adds](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md):

### Drupal Entity

```
{# Print a content block which ID is 1. #}
{{ drupal_entity('block_content', 1) }}

{# Print a node's teaser. #}
{{ drupal_entity('node', 123, 'teaser') }}

{# Print Branding block which was previously disabled on #}
{# admin/structure/block page. #}
{{ drupal_entity('block', 'bartik_branding', check_access=false) }}
```

### Drupal Field

```
{{ drupal_field('field_image', 'node', 1) }}

{{ drupal_field('field_image', 'node', 1, 'teaser') }}

{{ drupal_field('field_image', 'node', 1, {type: 'image_url', settings: {image_style: 'large'}}) }}
```

Comment: One more way is using `view` filter as follows
`{{ node.body|view }}`